# Role of RC in MOSFET Driver circuit

Tags: mosfet, transformer, pulse

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffHSOV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is for Full Bridge MOSFET driver. Switching Frequency is 400KHz.
Hardware is running as expected. Only thing i cannot understand the role of R1 & C1.

Comment: Pulse transformer and it's load aren't given and may be needed to calculate quantities. But \$M_2\$ is operating open-drain active-sourcing driver and that means there's no active sink. This leaves \$C_1\$ to resonate with the pulse transformer's remaining inductance. \$R_1\$ does double-duty, adding to the primary resistance of the pulse transformer when \$M_2\$ pulls high and dissipating some resonance energy when \$M_2\$ becomes inactive. However, I think \$C_1\$ is there to help absorb energy from the transformer and protect a potentially sensitive \$M_2\$ device, when driven inactive.

Comment: @jonk add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Not sure if this MOSFET driver works in real world. Where did you get this example?

Comment: @ jonk, oh you are bang on..[A]"C1 to resonate with the pulse transformer's remaining inductance".[B]"R1 does double-duty".I think they make LC circuit with a resistor in between.Hence please repost it as answer.

Comment: @Marko Buršič, This is working fine in Hardware.Output Waveform is ok.

Comment: Interesting, can you reveal what hardware is about? I'm curious.

Comment: This driver presently driving two mosfets irfp460 in HalfBridge .Transformer has 3 windings 1p-2sec.Load on bridge output is 500W Halogen Lamp.Taking 4Amp@225Volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pulse transformer and it's load aren't given and that may be needed to calculate quantities. But \$M_2\$ is operating as an open-drain, active-sourcing driver and that means there's no active sink there. This fact leaves \$C_1\$ to resonate with the pulse transformer's inductive component. \$R_1\$ does double-duty, adding to the primary resistance of the pulse transformer when \$M_2\$ pulls high and dissipating some resonance energy when \$M_2\$ becomes inactive. However, I think \$C_1\$ is also there to help absorb energy from the transformer and protect a potentially sensitive \$M_2\$ device, when driven inactive.